# \setlabel from chemnum package changes font size when used referred to in text

Tags: fontsize, labels, text, chemnum

Good evening,

I am using `\setlabel` from the chemnum package to rename some of my figures and make them contain references to other labelled compounds (`\cmpd`).

```
\documentclass[a5paper, 11pt, headinclude, footinclude, headsepline, footsepline, DIV10, twoside, openright]{scrbook}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{chemnum}

\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\replacecmpd{I}
\replacecmpd{I_II}\setcmpdlabel{I_II}{\cmpd{I}\_\cmpd{II}}
\replacecmpd{II}
    \includegraphics{60-CO2-HCOOH/Abbildungen/ameisensaure-rgl}
\captionof{figure}{caption}
\label{fig:formic-acid}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

I know how to change the fontsize within the graphics I am setting labels for (I am using `\setchemnum{format =\tiny, replace-style =\sffamily}`). Now, How can I adapt the label size used in the text? At the moment, all the labels set by `\setcmpdlabel` are smaller than the rest of the labels. adjusting one of the sizes would suffice for me to unify the style a little.

Thanks a million for you help!!

Comment: @clemens Thanks for editing the question. Did you have an anwer to the question as well?

Answer (score 1):

`chemnum` neither provides `\setlabel` nor `\setcmpdlabel`. I guess you refer to a suggestion of mine to another question here on tex.sx: [Defining own labels with chemnum 1.0](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/170177/) where I defined a macro `\setcmpdlabel`. I'll use it for this answer, too.

Since `format` changes the style of *all* labels but `replace-style` only the ones replaced in eps files you just need

```
\setchemnum{ replace-style = \tiny\sffamily }
```

Keep in mind that `replace-style` acts *in addition* to and *before* `format`.

```
\documentclass[a5paper, 11pt]{scrartcl}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{chemnum}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{auto-pst-pdf}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand \setcmpdlabel {mm}
  { \chemnum_compound_set_property:nnn {#1} {counter-representation} {#2} }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\setchemnum{ replace-style = \tiny\sffamily }

\begin{document}

\cmpd{I} xxx \cmpd{II}

\begin{center}
  \replacecmpd{I}
  \replacecmpd{I_II}\setcmpdlabel{I_II}{\cmpd{I}\_\cmpd{II}}
  \includegraphics{scheme-tmp.ps}
  \captionof{figure}{caption}
  \label{fig:formic-acid}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

[image]