# Labelling E and Z stereoisomers with chemnum

Tags: chemistry, psfrag, chemnum

I am currently writing my chemistry thesis, which is significantly focused on photoisomerisation. I am using chemnum for compound number. For example, here is azobenzene photoisomerisation: [image: E-Z azobenzene photomerisation]

As far as I am concerned, TMP1 is a single chemical compound and should be assigned a single label (say `\cmpd{azobenzene}` = **1**). Within text, I would then like to be able to refer to the E or Z photoisomers as *E*-**1** or *Z*-**1**. I can kind-of fake this by defining the compound `\cmpd{azobenzene}` and then manually calling `$E$-\cmpd{azobenzene}` or `$Z$-\cmpd{azobenzene}`, but this breaks down when it comes to renaming tags in `.eps` chemical structures (like the one shown above): unless there's some way to manually specify or modify the text `chemnum` uses to replace a temporary tag in an EPS file, there's no way to preface the compound numbers with *E-* or *Z-* as required.

As far as I can tell, my options are to either give each isomer a different numerical label (unacceptable) or label them as subcompounds with something like

```
\replacecmpd[tag=E-TMP1]{azobenzene.E}
\replacecmpd[tag=Z-TMP1]{azobenzene.Z}
```

which would allow me to call `Compounds \cmpd{azobenzene.E}, \cmpd{azobenzene.Z}` as

> Compounds **1a**, **1b**

which is still incorrect, unless there's a way to redefine `chemnum`'s subcompound logic replace lowercase latin suffices with *E*/*Z* prefixes.

Can anyone suggest a solution?

Edit: on playing around a little bit, this seems to be an *ok* solution to my problem:

```
\replacecmpd[tag=ETMP,pre-label-code=\textit{E-}]{Eazobenzene}
\resetcmpd[\cmpdproperty{Eazobenzene}{number}]
\replacecmpd[tag=ZTMP,pre-label-code=\textit{Z-}]{Zazobenzene}
\includegraphics{azobenzenes.eps}

Compounds \cmpd{Eazobenzene} and \cmpd{Zazobenzene}.
```

> Compounds *E*-**1** and *Z*-**1**.

This is acceptable, if a little clunky. Is there a better option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you've already found a working solution. :)

I propose another solution using a command `\setcmpdlabel` that I [first used in another answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/170196/) (and which I should probably add to `chemnum` as it proves useful again and again…).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chemnum}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\NewDocumentCommand \setcmpdlabel {mm}
  { \chemnum_compound_set_property:nnn {#1} {counter-representation} {#2} }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\newcommand*\defineEZcmpds[1]{%
  \cmpd*{#1}\cmpd*{E#1}\cmpd*{Z#1}%
  \setcmpdlabel{E#1}{\textit{E}-\cmpd{#1}}%
  \setcmpdlabel{Z#1}{\textit{Z}-\cmpd{#1}}%
}

\begin{document}

% defining
\defineEZcmpds{azobenzene}

% and using
Compounds \cmpd{Eazobenzene} and \cmpd{Zazobenzene} are the two photoisomers 
of \cmpd{azobenzene}.

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: That seems a little neater, so thank you. It still faces a difficulty in referring to the parent compound generally. My workaround right now is to use ```\textbf{\cmpdproperty{Eazobenzene}{counter-representation}}```, e.g.: ```\cmpd{Eazobenzene} and \cmpd{Zazobenzene} are the two photoisomers of \textbf{\cmpdproperty{Eazobenzene}{counter-representation}}.``` to receive "*E*-**1** and *Z*-**1** are the two photoisomers of **1**." Which is quite awkward, I think you'd agree. Perhaps in future an extension of the chemnum subcompound logic could be considered?

Comment: @ThomasMacDonald It doesn't, see my updated answer.

Comment: Very nice! Thanks, and marked as answered. I still think that generalisable subcompound labelling for prefixes would be a good feature to add at some point: E/Z, R/S/rac, fac/mer, cis/trans, Δ/Λ, etc etc.

Comment: @ThomasMacDonald all these are prefixes and I agree that there should be a mechanism. I think something along the lines of my answer here could be implemented (in a somewhat more generic way) in `chemnum`. I opened an issue so I don't forget: https://github.com/cgnieder/chemnum/issues/14

Comment: One more correction needed: your defined command doesn't reset compound numbering after it's done, so if two EZcompounds are defined sequentially they'll be numbered **1** and **4** (and the next compound will be **7**). My solution is to add ```\resetcmpd[\cmpdproperty{#1}{number}+1]%``` to the end of the ```\defineEZcmpds{}``` command definition.

Comment: @ThomasMacDonald yes, of course. I was just outlining an idea...